# How can I implement my trained neural net model on the 3D array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, image-processing, neural-network

I have a neural net model that was trained using 2D array of samples and features (1125, 8) (here 1125 is the number of samples and 8 is number of features). Now, I wanna use the model to predict on the feature layers 3D array (called 'finalyrs' in my code below) (8, 496, 495) (here 8 is the number of features (same features that were used at the training process) and (496, 495) are number of rows and columns in the imagery.) I could easily implement the model on the dataset with similar nd array of training dataset.  However, the case here is different. Could someone help me with the code that could implement the model and create an imagery classified into the desired number of classes?

```
#####Neural network
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=np.size(X_train, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',     
metrics= 
['accuracy'])

#Training the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=30)

#Prediction
finalyrs=np.array([R,G,B,h,s,EXG,GLI,WT])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_model():
Input_1 = Input(shape=(256, 512, 512, 1))
MaxPooling3D_27 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size= (1,3,3))(Input_1)
Convolution3D_1 = Convolution3D(kernel_dim1= 4,nb_filter= 10,activation= 'relu' ,kernel_dim3= 4,kernel_dim2= 4)(MaxPooling3D_27)
Convolution3D_7 = Convolution3D(kernel_dim1= 4,nb_filter= 10,activation= 'relu' ,kernel_dim3= 4,kernel_dim2= 4)(Convolution3D_1)
BatchNormalization_28 = BatchNormalization()(Convolution3D_7)
MaxPooling3D_12 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size= (2,2,2))(BatchNormalization_28)
SpatialDropout3D_1 = SpatialDropout3D(p= 0.5)(MaxPooling3D_12)
Convolution3D_9 = Convolution3D(kernel_dim1= 2,nb_filter= 20,activation= 'relu' ,kernel_dim3= 2,kernel_dim2= 2)(SpatialDropout3D_1)
Convolution3D_11 = Convolution3D(kernel_dim1= 2,nb_filter= 20,activation= 'relu' ,kernel_dim3= 2,kernel_dim2= 2)(Convolution3D_9)
BatchNormalization_9 = BatchNormalization()(Convolution3D_11)
MaxPooling3D_14 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size= (2,2,2))(BatchNormalization_9)
SpatialDropout3D_4 = SpatialDropout3D(p= 0.5)(MaxPooling3D_14)
Convolution3D_12 = Convolution3D(kernel_dim1= 2,nb_filter= 40,activation= 'relu' ,kernel_dim3= 2,kernel_dim2= 2)(SpatialDropout3D_4)
Convolution3D_13 = Convolution3D(kernel_dim1= 2,nb_filter= 40,activation= 'relu' ,kernel_dim3= 2,kernel_dim2= 2)(Convolution3D_12)
MaxPooling3D_23 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size= (2,2,2))(Convolution3D_13)
BatchNormalization_23 = BatchNormalization()(MaxPooling3D_23)
SpatialDropout3D_5 = SpatialDropout3D(p= 0.5)(BatchNormalization_23)
GlobalMaxPooling3D_1 = GlobalMaxPooling3D()(SpatialDropout3D_5)
Dense_1 = Dense(activation= 'relu' ,output_dim= 10)(GlobalMaxPooling3D_1)
Dropout_14 = Dropout(p= 0.3)(Dense_1)
Dense_6 = Dense(activation= 'relu' ,output_dim= 10)(Dropout_14)
Dense_2 = Dense(activation= 'softmax' ,output_dim= 2)(Dense_6)

return Model([Input_1],[Dense_2])
```

Comment: Thanks for uploading the codes for CNN. But, to be honest, this doesn't help at all. I am not trying to use deep learning model to classify images. I am trying to use artificial neural networks to classify pixel in the imagery into predefined classes.